# How to generically retrieve all children of a certain type in a root layout?

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-view, android-relativelayout

What I mean by my question (if I stated it ambiguously, as I couldn't find an answer to my question) is to take a root layout, get all children of that layout, and perform a callback on any that are an instanceof the specified type.

Now, I can do it in a fixed way, easily by doing something like...

```
RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
    for(int i = 0; i <= root.getChildCount(); i++){
        View v = root.getChildAt(i);
        if(v instanceof CustomLayout){
            // Do Callback on view.
        }
    }
```

Thing is, I want to make it more generic. I should be able to use any layout, and check to see if it is an instance of any layout. In particular, I want it generic enough to be used with anything (if this is even possible). Of course I don't mind stopping at just settling for layouts.

I want to build a collection of these children and return them, if possible of the same type. I haven't done Java in a long while so I'm very rusty, but I was thinking of using reflection to accomplish this. Is this at all possible?

If I pass the class of the type I want, is it possible?

Edit:

I didn't see dtann's answer before, must have missed it, but I did it on my own and it looks very similar to his. My implementation went something along the lines of this

```
public static abstract class CallbackOnRootChildren<T> {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void callOnChildren(Class<T> clazz, ViewGroup root) {
            for(int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount(); i++){
                View v = root.getChildAt(i);
                if(v instanceof ViewGroup){
                    callOnChildren(clazz, (ViewGroup) v);
                }
                if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(v.getClass())){
                    // The check to see if it is assignable ensures it's type safe.
                    onChild((T) v);
                }
            }
        }

        public abstract void onChild(T child);
    }
```

Difference is that mine relies on callbacks and whatnot, but overall same concept.

Comment: see `Class#isInstance(Object object)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
public <T> List<T>  getViewsByClass(View rootView, Class<T> targetClass) {
    List<T> items = new ArrayList<>();
    getViewsByClassRecursive(items,rootView,targetClass);
    return items;
}

private void getViewsByClassRecursive(List items, View view, Class clazz) {
    if (view.getClass().equals(clazz)) {
        Log.d("TAG","Found " + view.getClass().getSimpleName());
        items.add(view);
    }

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)view;
        if (viewGroup.getChildCount() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                getViewsByClassRecursive(items, viewGroup.getChildAt(i), clazz);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call `getViewsByClass` and pass in the root layout and target class. You should receive back a list of all the views that are instance of the target class. This would include the root layout itself if its also an instance of the target class. This method will search the entire view tree of the root layout.

Comment: use `Class#isInstance` instead of `Class#equals`, so to match any `View` you can simply use `View.class`

Comment: Was similar enough to my solution, and had I seen it earlier I'd have done yours.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way for this. If anyone does this will simply do the similarly.

Views in viewgroup are kept in field like (source-code):

```
// Child views of this ViewGroup
private View[] mChildren;
// Number of valid children in the mChildren array, the rest should be null or not
// considered as children
private int mChildrenCount;
```

[See documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

Comment: and so what that children are kept in View[] array?

Comment: simply, android does not have implementation for retrieving all views. You do have to implement your own method traversing recursively in view hierarchy and making conditional statement comparing each views